# Why does Oracle APEX Shared_Servers = 0 Break Apex 3.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-apex

Installed APEX 3.2 and set the shared_servers = 5 and APEX works great, but breaks other processes with our DB. So I set the shared_server = 0 again and now APEX won't show.

I'm using Oracle 11g and APEX 3.2. Does anyone have any ideas why APEX can't work with shared_servers=5?

Any/All help appreciated!

-JFV

Comment: What do you mean by "but breaks other processes with our DB"?

Comment: Apparently the Dispatchers prevent our DB from being restarted by other processes/servers (as part of our software system).

Answer (score 1):

[Configuring the SHARED_SERVERS Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/install.32/e13366/db_install.htm#CHDGDHDE)

> The embedded PL/SQL gateway uses the shared server architecture of the
>   Oracle Database. To achieve acceptable performance when using the
>   embedded PL/SQL gateway, ensure the  SHARED_SERVERS database
>   initialization parameter is set to a reasonable value (that is, not 0
>   or 1). For a small group of concurrent users, Oracle recommends a
>   value of 5 for SHARED_SERVERS.

It is a requirement for EPG (which is suitable only for a development environment). Better use OHS (or a J2EE web server for newer APEX versions).